# Problem mixing webforms into ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've been trying with the idea of taking an existing ASP.NET Webforms application and converting it to a hybrid so that going forward, we can do ASP.NET MVC.

In order to do this, I created an ASP.NET MVC application and started copying some of the folders from the ASP.NET webforms projects that contain webforms.  I'm having a problem building the resulting project getting hundreds of compile errors of this form:

```
Error   1951    'Documents_Admin_DocPushByTag' does not contain a definition for
'CtlCategoryList' and no extension method 'CtlCategoryList' accepting a first argument 
of type 'Documents_Admin_DocPushByTag' could be found (are you missing a using directive
or an assembly reference?)
```

Each of these error messages refer to server controls in my markup.  It's as if the mark-up is not getting parsed?  When I edit one of the code behind files and type **this.** to see what intellisense recognizes, these controls don't appear.  The event handlers do (but that must be because they are defined in the code behind file).  As far as I can tell, the **CodeFile** and **Inherits** Page attributes are correct (and unchanged from the ASP.NET project from whence they came).  I'm mystified what is causing this problem.  Any ideas?  TIA.

Answer (score 4):

check out how scott hanselman does it:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx

basicallly, you'd use ignoreroute to exclude all of your webforms from being routed to an mvc handler

Comment: Thanks.  I did see Scott's article.  However, my issue is happening during build.  Not during routing.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'd have a lot easier conversion adding the System.Web.Mvc assemblies to your current project and updating the web.config file and global.asax.

You have to make sure your current application is a web application (not site) project. If it isn't convert it and make sure it compiles first.

Comment: This sounds promising.  Indeed it is a web site project.