# webforms app as area of mvc application

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

i have main application, on mvc, with sexy routing, ant etc.
can i add existing webfroms application, as area of that application?
simple copy pase, causes many errors at compile time, maybe some dll doesnt exist, or config is not right? where can i read about it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [asp.net-mvc and webforms co-existing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842858/asp-net-mvc-and-webforms-co-existing)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think you can copy/paste your old ASP.Net ode and expect it to run under ASP.Net MVC.

But you have at least two options:

- I think it is possible to include an ASP.Net user control in an ASP.Net MVC site
- And you could always include the old site in an IFrame on your new site

Neither option is perfect, and may not be useable, but I don't think you will get further with your old code.

Comment: what about authentification? cani pass it to iframe?

Comment: @eba that depends. I suppose it will be hard if you use a cookie to store the authentication token, but you may be able to pass on the token in a query string. You could possibly modify your old site so that it uses the authentication from the new site. That should be possible if they can access the same database.

Comment: Hehe. Yeah. It will be a dirty hack, but it should work. The ideal solution would be to rewrite your site to use MVC. Try to get more money from whoever pays for your project :-D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. [Professional ASP.NET MVC 1.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470384611) has a chapter dedicated to Webforms and MVC together.  There are also other Stack Overflow questions that deal with it:

- [ASP.NET MVC and WebForms coexisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842858/asp-net-mvc-and-webforms-co-existing)
- [Problem mixing Webforms in an MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297895/problem-mixing-webforms-into-asp-net-mvc-application)